# Problems with Homebrew - `brew upgrade` and `brew install git` result in errors

Tags: homebrew, upgrade, error, git

I am a novice homebrew user (on a mac), so please forgive my incompetence. I ran into some problems while exploring the basic functionality.

After executing the command `brew outdated` and getting the following output:

```
gettext (0.19.8.1) < 0.21
glib (2.56.2) < 2.68.2
gmp (6.1.2_2) < 6.2.1
gnutls (3.5.19) < 3.6.16
jpeg (9c) < 9d
libffi (3.2.1) < 3.3_3
libpng (1.6.35) < 1.6.37
libtasn1 (4.13) < 4.17.0
nettle (3.4) < 3.7.2
p11-kit (0.23.14) < 0.23.22
pcre (8.42) < 8.44
pixman (0.34.0_1) < 0.40.0
qemu (3.0.0) < 6.0.0
```

I want to know how to update these. However after executing `brew upgrade` the following output full of errors  comes up (also it is red at the end). I do not understand what the problem is, and after executing `brew outdated` again I see that the upgrades weren't successful.

Any help will be much appreciated!

```
Updating Homebrew...
==> Upgrading 13 outdated packages:
gmp 6.1.2_2 -> 6.2.1
libpng 1.6.35 -> 1.6.37
nettle 3.4 -> 3.7.2
pixman 0.34.0_1 -> 0.40.0
glib 2.56.2 -> 2.68.2
gettext 0.19.8.1 -> 0.21
qemu 3.0.0 -> 6.0.0
libtasn1 4.13 -> 4.17.0
pcre 8.42 -> 8.44
jpeg 9c -> 9d
p11-kit 0.23.14 -> 0.23.22
libffi 3.3_3
gnutls 3.5.19 -> 3.6.16
==> Upgrading libffi -> 3.3_3 
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/libffi/manifests/3.3_3
Already downloaded: /Users/Vladimir/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/579ebe43f9cb570f21b0b4deb5906e9e833291b57639d94ff691b9377cbfdddd--libffi-3.3_3.bottle_manifest.json
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/libffi/blobs/sha256:8a7a02cffb368dfdeaeb1176a7a7bcc
Already downloaded: /Users/Vladimir/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/8f0286cf28930b83052c9ddff88bd4cc4636bbde4b0c78e67bcbcfa794337937--libffi--3.3_3.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring libffi--3.3_3.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3: Permission denied
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3: unable to copy extended attributes to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3: Permission denied
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/LICENSE-BUILDTOOLS: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/INSTALL_RECEIPT.json: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/LICENSE: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/.brew: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3/.brew: unable to copy extended attributes to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/.brew: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/.brew/libffi.rb: No such file or directory
cp: setattrlist: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/.brew: No such file or directory
cp: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/.brew: No such file or directory
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/.brew: No such file or directory
cp: chflags: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/.brew: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3/.brew: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/.brew: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/ChangeLog: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/include: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3/include: unable to copy extended attributes to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/include: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/include/ffitarget.h: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/include/ffi.h: No such file or directory
cp: setattrlist: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/include: No such file or directory
cp: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/include: No such file or directory
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/include: No such file or directory
cp: chflags: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/include: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3/include: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/include: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/README.md: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/lib: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3/lib: unable to copy extended attributes to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/lib: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/lib/pkgconfig: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3/lib/pkgconfig: unable to copy extended attributes to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/lib/pkgconfig: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/lib/pkgconfig/libffi.pc: No such file or directory
cp: setattrlist: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/lib/pkgconfig: No such file or directory
cp: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/lib/pkgconfig: No such file or directory
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/lib/pkgconfig: No such file or directory
cp: chflags: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/lib/pkgconfig: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3/lib/pkgconfig: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/lib/pkgconfig: No such file or directory
cp: symlink: libffi.7.dylib: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/lib/libffi.7.dylib: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/lib/libffi.a: No such file or directory
cp: setattrlist: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/lib: No such file or directory
cp: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/lib: No such file or directory
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/lib: No such file or directory
cp: chflags: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/lib: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3/lib: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/lib: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3/share: unable to copy extended attributes to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man: unable to copy extended attributes to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man/man3: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man/man3: unable to copy extended attributes to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man/man3: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man/man3/ffi_call.3: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man/man3/ffi_prep_cif_var.3: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man/man3/ffi_prep_cif.3: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man/man3/ffi.3: No such file or directory
cp: setattrlist: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man/man3: No such file or directory
cp: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man/man3: No such file or directory
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man/man3: No such file or directory
cp: chflags: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man/man3: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man/man3: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man/man3: No such file or directory
cp: setattrlist: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man: No such file or directory
cp: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man: No such file or directory
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man: No such file or directory
cp: chflags: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/info: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3/share/info: unable to copy extended attributes to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/info: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/info/libffi.info: No such file or directory
cp: setattrlist: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/info: No such file or directory
cp: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/info: No such file or directory
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/info: No such file or directory
cp: chflags: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/info: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3/share/info: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/info: No such file or directory
cp: setattrlist: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share: No such file or directory
cp: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share: No such file or directory
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share: No such file or directory
cp: chflags: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3/share: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share: No such file or directory
cp: setattrlist: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3: No such file or directory
cp: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3: No such file or directory
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3: No such file or directory
cp: chflags: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3: Permission denied
cp: setattrlist: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/.: Permission denied
Error: Failure while executing; `cp -pR /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/. /usr/local/Cellar/libffi` exited with 1. Here's the output:
```

#### It continues but from this point in red colour:

```
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3: Permission denied
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3: unable to copy extended attributes to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3: Permission denied
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/LICENSE-BUILDTOOLS: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/INSTALL_RECEIPT.json: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/LICENSE: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/.brew: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3/.brew: unable to copy extended attributes to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/.brew: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/.brew/libffi.rb: No such file or directory
cp: setattrlist: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/.brew: No such file or directory
cp: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/.brew: No such file or directory
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/.brew: No such file or directory
cp: chflags: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/.brew: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3/.brew: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/.brew: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/ChangeLog: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/include: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3/include: unable to copy extended attributes to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/include: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/include/ffitarget.h: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/include/ffi.h: No such file or directory
cp: setattrlist: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/include: No such file or directory
cp: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/include: No such file or directory
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/include: No such file or directory
cp: chflags: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/include: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3/include: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/include: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/README.md: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/lib: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3/lib: unable to copy extended attributes to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/lib: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/lib/pkgconfig: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3/lib/pkgconfig: unable to copy extended attributes to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/lib/pkgconfig: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/lib/pkgconfig/libffi.pc: No such file or directory
cp: setattrlist: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/lib/pkgconfig: No such file or directory
cp: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/lib/pkgconfig: No such file or directory
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/lib/pkgconfig: No such file or directory
cp: chflags: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/lib/pkgconfig: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3/lib/pkgconfig: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/lib/pkgconfig: No such file or directory
cp: symlink: libffi.7.dylib: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/lib/libffi.7.dylib: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/lib/libffi.a: No such file or directory
cp: setattrlist: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/lib: No such file or directory
cp: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/lib: No such file or directory
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/lib: No such file or directory
cp: chflags: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/lib: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3/lib: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/lib: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3/share: unable to copy extended attributes to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man: unable to copy extended attributes to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man/man3: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man/man3: unable to copy extended attributes to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man/man3: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man/man3/ffi_call.3: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man/man3/ffi_prep_cif_var.3: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man/man3/ffi_prep_cif.3: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man/man3/ffi.3: No such file or directory
cp: setattrlist: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man/man3: No such file or directory
cp: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man/man3: No such file or directory
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man/man3: No such file or directory
cp: chflags: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man/man3: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man/man3: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man/man3: No such file or directory
cp: setattrlist: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man: No such file or directory
cp: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man: No such file or directory
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man: No such file or directory
cp: chflags: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/man: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/info: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3/share/info: unable to copy extended attributes to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/info: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/info/libffi.info: No such file or directory
cp: setattrlist: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/info: No such file or directory
cp: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/info: No such file or directory
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/info: No such file or directory
cp: chflags: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/info: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3/share/info: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share/info: No such file or directory
cp: setattrlist: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share: No such file or directory
cp: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share: No such file or directory
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share: No such file or directory
cp: chflags: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3/share: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3/share: No such file or directory
cp: setattrlist: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3: No such file or directory
cp: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3: No such file or directory
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3: No such file or directory
cp: chflags: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-13050-1nloc82/libffi/./3.3_3: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/./3.3_3: Permission denied
cp: setattrlist: /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/.: Permission denied
```

---

#### Here is the output of `brew doctor`:

```
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and which additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew-provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3-config

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
  /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.55.52.102.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libavformat.55.33.100.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libavutil.52.66.100.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libcgunwind.1.0.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/liblua.5.1.5.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libswscale.2.5.102.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libtcl8.6.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libtk8.6.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libx264.129.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
  /usr/local/include/fakemysql.h
  /usr/local/include/fakepq.h
  /usr/local/include/fakesql.h
  /usr/local/include/itcl.h
  /usr/local/include/itcl2TclOO.h
  /usr/local/include/itclDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/itclInt.h
  /usr/local/include/itclIntDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/itclMigrate2TclCore.h
  /usr/local/include/itclTclIntStubsFcn.h
  /usr/local/include/mysqlStubs.h
  /usr/local/include/odbcStubs.h
  /usr/local/include/pqStubs.h
  /usr/local/include/tcl.h
  /usr/local/include/tclDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/tclOO.h
  /usr/local/include/tclOODecls.h
  /usr/local/include/tclPlatDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/tclThread.h
  /usr/local/include/tclTomMath.h
  /usr/local/include/tclTomMathDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/tdbc.h
  /usr/local/include/tdbcDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/tdbcInt.h
  /usr/local/include/tk.h
  /usr/local/include/tkDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/tkPlatDecls.h

Warning: Unbrewed '.pc' files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected '.pc' files:
  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/tcl.pc
  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/tk.pc

Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
  /usr/local/lib/libtclstub8.6.a
  /usr/local/lib/libtkstub8.6.a

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar.
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause formulae that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
  pkg-config
  gettext
```

---

##### I also run into similar problem when trying to install git by `brew install git`, which is really frustrating!

The output there is too large to include (825186 characters in 6853 lines) but here is some of it from the beginning and the end:

```
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/gettext/manifests/0.21
Already downloaded: /Users/Vladimir/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/66569d4eb02ec67195446d3dcba7d7806a35f88f629a55b43ba53fb1febb1f56--gettext-0.21.bottle_manifest.json
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/gettext/blobs/sha256:a025e143fe3f5f7e24a936b8b0a4926acfdd025b11d62024e3d355c106536d56
Already downloaded: /Users/Vladimir/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/56f8e2a346bf8ce27f5f2aadbc0b3163e78d8cae1fcfd9f462477cd4b821479f--gettext--0.21.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/pcre2/manifests/10.37
Already downloaded: /Users/Vladimir/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/a60945ab62014571a4bcc94b411b35f6ad1c6b42904b9fcd8277b54f0a3d86d9--pcre2-10.37.bottle_manifest.json
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/pcre2/blobs/sha256:981738c8279de442ac2fc83fa61e9cdf75e5c26b19a6d7fc2179362da2d522f7
Already downloaded: /Users/Vladimir/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/753ea6acc335ceec799fcc28c9ab62db7d1a9f14c11d1d9c65ba8aff55918e53--pcre2--10.37.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/git/manifests/2.31.1
Already downloaded: /Users/Vladimir/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/c5e6b7ec853292fe4e17f803227e1fa9f37d346ce9f554ef9067141a8551019d--git-2.31.1.bottle_manifest.json
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/git/blobs/sha256:cf1fe81d5928efa530d891ec341d34c262b1eb7ea457191359476168ae323b93
Already downloaded: /Users/Vladimir/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/e8b66f09a85dba187dfa878a52f9dbc5be1e41583751989698fcce7f75780d4b--git--2.31.1.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
==> Installing dependencies for git: gettext and pcre2
==> Installing git dependency: gettext
==> Pouring gettext--0.21.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
     
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21: Permission denied
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-17423-14t8cmq/gettext/./0.21: unable to copy extended attributes to /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21: Permission denied
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/INSTALL_RECEIPT.json: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/bin: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-17423-14t8cmq/gettext/./0.21/bin: unable to copy extended attributes to /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/bin: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/bin/msgconv: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/bin/msggrep: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/bin/autopoint: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/bin/msgcomm: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/bin/msgen: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/bin/msgmerge: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/bin/envsubst: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/bin/msginit: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/bin/gettext: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/bin/gettext.sh: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/bin/msgcmp: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/bin/msgcat: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/bin/recode-sr-latin: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/bin/msgexec: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/bin/ngettext: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/bin/msgunfmt: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/bin/msgfilter: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/bin/msgfmt: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/bin/msgattrib: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/bin/xgettext: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/bin/gettextize: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/bin/msguniq: No such file or directory
cp: setattrlist: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/bin: No such file or directory
cp: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/bin: No such file or directory
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/bin: No such file or directory
cp: chflags: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/bin: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-17423-14t8cmq/gettext/./0.21/bin: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/bin: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/.brew: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-17423-14t8cmq/gettext/./0.21/.brew: unable to copy extended attributes to /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/.brew: No such file or directory

...
...
...

cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-17423-14t8cmq/gettext/./0.21/share/gettext-0.21: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/share/gettext-0.21: No such file or directory
cp: setattrlist: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/share: No such file or directory
cp: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/share: No such file or directory
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/share: No such file or directory
cp: chflags: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/share: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-17423-14t8cmq/gettext/./0.21/share: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21/share: No such file or directory
cp: setattrlist: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21: No such file or directory
cp: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21: No such file or directory
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21: No such file or directory
cp: chflags: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20210603-17423-14t8cmq/gettext/./0.21: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/./0.21: Permission denied
cp: setattrlist: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/.: Permission denied
```

Comment: brew thinks you have installed some things not using brew into /usr/local/. I think these include python, tcl and media program e.g. vlc, ffmpeg and then I suspect something has put standard Unix permissions on /usr/local ie only writeable by root on /usr/local. Homebrew conflicts with this standard. So if you build programs by using ./configure etc then you can't easily use homebrew. If you understand why then you can work around it but that requires more Unix knowledge than can fit in an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up uninstalling homebrew from my system. A message showed up that several directories in usr/local could not be deleted because of permission issues. So, I deleted all of them manually.

After that I installed homebrew again, and the problem seems to have been solved.